# Verify no pre-released NuGet references when merging to main

Tags: msbuild, nuget, github-actions, csproj

### Background

We have few .net projects in different GitHub repositories with dependencies among them. The dependencies are established using NuGet packages that reside in Artifactory.

When we want to test a change to a library, we publish a pre-release version from a branch on the *library's* repo, consume the pre-released version from a branch on the consuming project and perform the tests. When we're satisfied with the results, we merge the changes in the library's repo to its "main" branch, release an official version of the NuGet, update the branch of the consuming project with the official version and then we merge the consuming project to its "main" branch too.

We use GitHub actions to build and run the tests before merging a PR to each repo's "main" branch.

### The problem

This process is pretty manual, and I'm especially concerned about the last part: we want to verify that we don't accidentally merge a reference to a pre-release version of the NuGet to the consuming project's "main" branch.

### My question, and few notes

How can we verify that a project doesn't have a reference to a pre-release NuGet package?

Notes:

- I thought to parse the XML of the csproj files for that. However, some projects use **Directory.Build.props**, and even some more sophisticated structures that make it harder. If we could somehow intervene in the MS-Build process it would be best, but I don't know how
- We have few repos that produce NuGet packages, each of these repos produce several related packages, but all packages produced from a single repo all have the same version number. In the consuming projects we usually do something like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectAVersion>1.2.3-prerelease0001</ProjectAVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ProjectA.X" Version="$(ProjectAVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="ProjectA.Y" Version="$(ProjectAVersion)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

However, I wouldn't rely on this structure, as developers may (accidentally or not) add a dependency directly in the "normal" way.

- I don't want to prevent the use of pre-release versions of 3rd party libraries, or at least provide a way to ignore specific ones (I know we have at least one such dependency in many projects). We can differentiate our packages from 3rd-party ones either by their prefix (all of our packages start with the name of the company and the group), or by the source where the package is found (internal Artifactory vs. NuGet.org; but this is known only by during the `dotnet restore` process. I don't know if we have a simple way to get this information)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can extend your MSBuild projects with [Directory.Build.props and Directory.Build.targets files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022). These files, if they exist, are automatically imported into a project. `PackageReference` is an [item collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2022). The `Version` is metadata on items in the collection. Whether the `Version` is set from a literal or a property doesn't matter. With the `PackageReference` collection check the package names and the versions.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanDodds. It looks like a good direction. Can you elaborate on it more and provide a full example? 

Comment: Yes, I started working on an example. (But I can't give it my full attention and can't predict when it will be ready.)